# React Native,PushNotification for iOS 10 gives "UIUserNotificationSettings is deprecated"

Tags: ios, react-native

When settings iOS 10 as the build target for React Native, I get this error

> /Users/krishan/Projects/CandidApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.h:15:46: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can use "UserNotifications"
you just import it and use its two delegate method as bellow:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

       print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
  }

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
   print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Opps I don't know about the react native library can u explain something about it because I m new in iOS swift